# Why does Java convert my characters into weird question marks?

Tags: java, unicode

Let me explain. I have a string which is JoaquÃ­n Torres GarcÃ­a and then when I parse it using the above code, the txt file generated has the same name in form of Joa???? Torres Garc????a. I am writing the strings composed in this fashion to the text file using this code:

```
java.util.Iterator<String> itr = set.iterator();
        int occur = 0;

        File w = new File("newnodes.txt");

                try (BufferedWriter wr = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(w))) {
                //String def = "nodedef>name VARCHAR,label VARCHAR";
                //wr.write(def);
                wr.newLine();
                    while (itr.hasNext()) {
                        occur++;
                        String str = (String.valueOf(occur))+","+ (itr.next());
                        wr.write(str);
                        wr.newLine();

                    }
                System.out.println("Node file Created");
```

Comment: 1. You are using too many parentheses. 2. You have an encoding problem which cannot be solved by just those 3 lines. You should provide an [SCCE](http://sscce.org).

Comment: Where does the value `occur` come from?  Why do you think it's what you say it is?

Comment: Guys, occur is basically a count i.e. numbers so that is fine.. More code has been added to the Question.

Comment: Not enough info. It could be the input file,  the limits of the console, or the text editor. All of them have to use the same encoding.

Comment: Yes, the input file has non unicode characters so I want it to be that way, it doesn't matter, but at least not this ?????. I am using Eclipse on a Mac.

Comment: I am quite sure your input file does NOT have non Unicode characters in it.

Comment: Yes, that's right. Now, the parser should still be able to print non Unicode characters instead of ??????. That's my question. Why doesn't it?

Comment: No, the parser should NOT be able to print non Unicode characters.  But that's OK, because your input file doesn't contain any.

Comment: My input file doesn't contain any UNICODE characters, and once I run that file and create a new one is when the issue occurs, shows up ??????? in random places.

Comment: So, what's encoding of your file?

Comment: Ali, I think you should go and read up on what Unicode is, and what character encodings are.  When you've done that, I think you'll probably be able to work out for yourself what the issue is.  But right now, it's difficult to help you, because you are saying things that don't make too much sense.

Comment: I fixed it, had to change the Eclipse Workspace setting to UTF-8. Thanks for your support guys. Love you for being so prompt in replies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use UTF-8 Writter

```
File w = new File("newnodes.txt");
try (Writer out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(w), "UTF-8")))     {
//stuff here..
```

Comment: I don't think outputting unicode is the main issue. Either the input is read wrong, or the text editor is showing it wrong.